# No joy package in noetic?

Tags: ros, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot find or install the `ros-noetic-joy` package. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and installed ROS Noetic according to the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu

When I search for it, I get the following:

```
$ apt search ros-noetic-joy
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
ros-noetic-joy-teleop/focal,now 0.4.0-1focal.20200608.160320 amd64 [installed]
  A (to be) generic joystick interface to control a robot

ros-noetic-joystick-interrupt/focal 0.8.8-1focal.20200616.142941 amd64
  Interrupt cmd_vel by joystick input

ros-noetic-joystick-interrupt-dbgsym/focal 0.8.8-1focal.20200616.142941 amd64
  debug symbols for ros-noetic-joystick-interrupt
```

Is the `joy` package available in noetic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356864/no-joy-package-in-noetic?/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2020-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its been released https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/noetic/distribution.yaml and the builds successful http://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_uF64__joy__ubuntu_focal_amd64__binary/. The last sync was a couple days before https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-noetic-2020-07-03/15232 so its available just not released to apt yet. You can access it with shadow fixed or build from source.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2020-07-10**:
Thanks. Do you know when it might be released to apt?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-07-10**:
A new sync should happen within a couple weeks, after which it will be available via the main apt repo

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2020-07-10**:
Got it, thanks.

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2020-08-12**:
Released! These packages are now available:
ros-noetic-joy
ros-noetic-joy-dbgsym
ros-noetic-joystick-drivers
ros-noetic-joystick-interrupt
ros-noetic-joystick-interrupt-dbgsym
ros-noetic-joy-teleop